# Limiting number of allowed ips for a single apache user - preventing username abuse

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to limit the number of IP addresses an Apache user can use, before being blocked. I've set up multiple users under a .htaccess system - but I cannot work out how to limit IPs for individual users.

eg. user 'fred' connects via 2 separate IP addresses, I want to make sure that if fred's details get out, the system halts after 5-10 separate addresses are used.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read [this article on the x y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147520), then tell us what the problem is you're trying solve.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but unfortunately I don't have any easy answer. You'd basically require a separate database of who has connected from where, and a way for the user to confirm/deny whether a new IP should be allowed or not. If there's any such module for Apache I've not been able to find it.

Comment: Hi Iain, Thanks for that.

THe problem I'm trying to solve is to make sure that users on a paid server do not share their username/passwords - and are limited if they do so.

I'm happy for them to use the service at work/home etc, but if they share it with lots of friends, then we have a problem...

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this using mod-auth-external, in combination with a custom password checker. This external password checker does get the clients' IP passed from apache, so can check it against some database.

https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/

Comment: Thanks for that Krist - will check it out and let you know!